# Use a model's function in a middleware?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and am creating a "Admin" middleware to check that a user has right to access a specific page.

I would like to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest() or !$this->auth->user()->isAdmin())
        return redirect()->guest('auth/signin');

    return $next($request);
}
```

So I achieve my goal like this, but it seems weird:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest() or ! User::find($this->auth->user()->id)->isAdmin())
        return redirect()->guest('auth/signin');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Any suggestion? Am I missing something?

Comment: try if `dd( $this->auth->user() )` gives you an instance of `User` (it should)

Comment: Your if statement is bad, because guest by default can't be an admin. You should create another middleware where check user is admin and put it after guest middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, thank you for your help:

I had two User class (one in `App\User` and one ine `App\Models\User`). I changed my configuration in `config/auth.php` to set the model to `App\Models\User::class` and deleted the default User model present when installing Laravel. So now the isAdmin() function works.

And as xAoc told me, the code is now the following:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$this->auth->user()->isAdmin())
        return redirect()->guest('auth/signin');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but if you copied your code
 `!$this->auth->user-()->isAdmin()`
, is error. After **user** you have "`-()`"

Comment: It was an error when I copied the code. Thank you for your help.